# Calculating age on the basis of date format dynamicallly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have three formats stored in database setting table.

```
<select>
  <option value="d-m-Y">dd/mm/yyyy</option>
  <option value="Y-m-d">yyyy/mm/dd</option>
  <option value="m-d-Y">mm/dd/yyyy</option>
</select>
```

I am able to get the format value like `d-m-Y` or `Y-m-d` or `m-d-Y` in the line

```
var dateFormat = getDateFormat(); //of the below code.

function GetAge(dateString) 
{
  var today = new Date();
  var dateFormat = getDateFormat();
  var birthDate = new Date(dateString);

  var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
  var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
  if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) 
  {
    age--;
  }
  return age;
}
```

Now I want that it should check format first then calculate the age... 
Please help me !!!

Comment: So what exactly is the issue with your current code?

Comment: where you used `dateFormat` ??

Comment: show us a live demo

Comment: Actually I am not able to tweak the above code for checking format. For e.g if user has entered date 12/12/1986 how will it know whether it is 12 month or date. If the date format in database is "m-d-y" and the entered date is 23/12/1986 then how will it know whether 23 is month or not... Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are  using `jquery ui` so before calculation use `datepicker.formatDate` like this.

```
  var dateFormat = getDateFormat();// Return pattern  yy-mm-dd
  var today =$.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat , new Date());;
  var birthDate = $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat , new Date(dateString));
  //Your age calculation logic
```